# Foreign constraints in QLDB table

Tags: amazon-qldb

Is there a way to add foreign constraints in a QLDB table?

Suppose I have two open tables, one with and another without, a *primary key*. Can I add a foreign key constraint referencing those with a primary key?

Does the same work with indexes? If I don't have any primary keys, but only indexes on the tables, can I add foreign key referencing these indexes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Primary Key or Foreign Key concept in QLDB at this time.

[Document IDs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.docs.html#ql-reference.docs.id) are a closely related concept to Primary Keys in that each Document ID is a universally unique identifier.

To enforce Foreign Constraints on the application-level, you can [SELECT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html) before  [UPDATE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.update.html) or [DELETE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.delete.html) or [DROP TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.drop-table.html) in a transaction to ensure the referential integrity of the Foreign Key.